# synchronized hover of two different elements

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, hover

I'm trying to make a website with a duplicated body in a div called `#front`. There is also the classic body which is named `#back`.

**What I would like to do is to have synchronized hovers over the two differents divs `#front` & `#back`**. So this is working fine when there is only one, but it's not as soon as you add more links, since it will apply the effects to all the `a` and not only **the one you are hovering and it's corresponding one in the other `div`.**

For exemple:
I would like to hover "amet" in `#back` to have "amet in `#front` in the same style but I don't want "other amet" in `#back` and `#front` with the same style.

I was wondering if this could be done without having `ids` on the elements, but if it's not, it's also great.
Thanks for the help!

```js
$("a").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
     
    $("#front a, #back a").css({
    "font-style": "italic"
    })
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
   
    $("#front a, #back a").css({
    "font-style": "normal"
    })
    }
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
 
}
#front {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 35%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
#back {
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a:hover{
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class ="scroll" id="back">
  <a href="#">amet</a> &
  <a href="#">other amet</a>
</div>

<div class ="scroll" id="front">
  <a href="#">amet</a> &
  <a href="#">other amet</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do what you require you can relate the two elements by index within their respective containers using `:nth-child`. Try this:

```js
$("a").on('mouseenter mouseleave', e => {
  let index = $(e.target).index();
  $(`#front a:nth-child(${index + 1}), #back a:nth-child(${index + 1})`).css('font-style', e.type == 'mouseenter' ? 'italic' : 'normal')
});
```

```css
.scroll {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

#front {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  margin: auto auto auto auto;
  width: 25%;
  height: 35%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#back {
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a:hover {
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="scroll" id="back">
  <a href="#">amet</a> &amp;
  <a href="#">other amet</a>
</div>

<div class="scroll" id="front">
  <a href="#">amet</a> &amp;
  <a href="#">other amet</a>
</div>
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the help, but this is not really what I asked for

Comment: actually, as I said, I would like the links in `#front` & `#back` to have the same style when I hover them. So this is working.
But on the other hand I would like to avoid to have **all** of my `a` to have this effect. (amet and other amet at the same time)

Comment: Given your edit I updated the answer - hopefully this matches your requirement

Comment: I apologize for the early confusion :)
Have a wonderful evening